# How do you delete a character in starbound?

Tags: starbound

Just got Starbound, and I made a typo in my first character's name. My OCD has kicked in, and I want to delete him. I see no delete button anywhere, and hovering + pressing delete over my characters do not work.

Advice please :)?

**Edit**

This post is really old and not relevant anymore due to the implementation of the character delete button in later versions!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to `Steam\SteamApps\common\Starbound\player`. There you find your character and world files. At a first glance, there is no way to tell which one is which though, since it uses some sort of hasing to create filenames. So you should look at the file creation date and also make a backup before deleting it.

Alternativly, you can open the file with notepad and have a peek inside. Your name is there on the top after the "ACK" Symbol:

[image]

My character name is Gordon, so I know this is the right file.

Comment: Could the OP alternatively rename the character in that file and satiate their OCD without losing their progress? If not, doesn't that mean the name is keyed elsewhere in the data and that deleting this file is a messy solution?

Comment: You would need to write the file back in binary mode. So no, opening it with notepad and editing it is a very bad idea.

Comment: You could still try. Obviously notepad is a bad tool for the job and I would suggest another, but approaching the problem this way is an option, isn't it? For example, Notepad++ is one of my favourite tools and can copy/paste as binary so with the hex plug-in, you can easily figure out and replace the binary data to change the name.

Comment: Notepad++ is not the stock windows Notepad.

Comment: Really? It's almost like I just said I would suggest another tool than notepad and then gave an example of one. :/ My question is whether the approach would work to not have to delete the file and lose progress, but still achieve the OP's goal.

Comment: Decent. Will get to work on this when I get home and check it out. Still dumb that you have to go to these lengths to delete a character (which should be a common function to do).

That's why we love beta versions

Comment: Editing this file to change a name could be bad. The file keeps track of how long the name is, the ACK character just prior to "Gordon" in the provided example should be HEX 06, which tells the game the length of the following string. Changing the string to a different length without adjusting the length bit would likely break things.

Comment: worked for me :)

Comment: Really? 60K views and only 3 answers That go up to ONLY 7 up votes? well...

Answer (score 4):

Upbeat Giraffe has added delete capability to the character select screen. Simply click on the trash icon associated with the character and you will be able to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try placing all your character's items in their ship, making a new character, and copying and renaming the shipworld file to the new char. I had the same problem, and this worked for me.